# Solving NUMROUTE in IARCS

Tags: c++, algorithm

Link to the problem is ([Docs](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/contests/oct2005/Advanced-2.php))
Although I solved it using the below code, it gives `SEG` fault as `len<=10^9` and my program probably runs out of stack memory. How do I optimize it? Or is there a better solution to it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
#define pb push_back

struct nd
{
    int val;int times;  
};
vector<list<nd> > adj_list;
int end;
int recur(int node, int len)
{ list<nd> ::iterator it;
    if(len==1)
    {//cout<<"reaching "<<node<<endl;
        int y=0;
        for(it=adj_list[node].begin(); it!=adj_list[node].end(); it++)
        {
            if((it->val)==end){y=it->times+y;}

        }
        return y;

    }
    else {
        int sum=0;
            //cout<<"going "<<node<<" length "<<len<<endl;
        for(it=adj_list[node].begin(); it!=adj_list[node].end(); it++)
        {

        sum+=it->times*recur(it->val,len-1);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
int main()
{

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    adj_list.resize(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            int a;cin>>a;
            nd temp;
            temp.val=j;temp.times=a;
            adj_list[i].pb(temp);
        }
    }
    int st,len;
    cin>>st>>end>>len;
    st--;end--;
    list<nd> ::iterator it;
    int ans=0;
    for(it=adj_list[st].begin(); it!=adj_list[st].end(); it++)
    {
        int p=it->times*recur(it->val,len-1);
            //cout<<*it<<" "<<p<<endl;
        ans+=p;
    }
    cout<<ans%42373<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You mean something like using a dynamically allocated queue or stack data structure to convert the recursive algorithm into an iterative one so that you don't crunch your call stack?

Comment: I guess that too wont work as len <= 10^9 as we dont have so much memory . Th problem statement suggested only 64 mb of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an adjacency matrix `A` for the multi-graph and take the `k`th power of it. The `i,j`th entry of the resulting matrix is the number of walks from node `i` to node `j`.

Example: we have two nodes, `0` and `1`, with two connections between them, `a` and `b`.

```
   0
  / \
 a   b
  \ /
   1
```

The adjacency matrix is

```
0 2
2 0
```

and the second power of that is

```
4 0 
0 4
```

And indeed, there are four walks of length 2 from node 0 to node 0: `aa, ab, ba, bb`.

[Here're a few notes on this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/184a_ch10.3_slides-handout.pdf).

As an aside, you can calculate large powers very quickly using [binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_exponentiation).