# Matrix Exponentiation for calculating number of routes possible

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, matrix-multiplication

Recently I came across [this](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/NUMROUTE) problem in the Iarcs website. Here is the problem statement:

> It is well known that the routing algorithm used on the Internet is
>   highly non-optimal. A "hop", in Internet jargon, is a pair of nodes
>   that are directly connected - by a cable or a microwave link or
>   whatever. The number of hops that a packet may take in going from one
>   node to another may be far more than the minimum required.
>
> But the routing algorithm used by the Siruseri Network company is
>   worse. Here, a packet sent from one node to another could even go
>   through the same node twice or even traverse the same hop twice before
>   it eventually finds its way to its destination. Sometimes a packet
>   even goes through the destination more than once before it is
>   considered "delivered". Suppose the network in Siruseri consisted of
>   the following nodes and cables: Figure
>
> There are 5 nodes and 8 cable links. Note that a pair of nodes may be
>   connected by more than one link. These are considered to be different
>   hops. All links are bidirectional. A packet from node 1 to node 5 may,
>   for example, travel as follows: 1 to 2, 2 to 1, 1 to 3, 3 to 2, 2 to
>   1, 1 to 4, 4 to 5, 5 to 4, 4 to 5. This routing is of length 9 (the
>   number of hops is the length of a given routing). We are interested in
>   counting the number of different routings from a given source to a
>   target that are of a given length.
>
> For example, the number of routings from 1 to 2 of length 3 are 7.
>   They are as follows (separated by ;): 1 to 2, 2 to 1 and 1 to 2; 1 to
>   3, 3 to 1 and 1 to 2; 1 to 4, 4 to 1 and 1 to 2; 1 to 5, 5 to 1 and 1
>   to 2; 1 to 4, 4 to 3 (via the left cable) and 3 to 2; 1 to 4, 4 to 3
>   (via the right cable) and 3 to 2; 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and 3 to 2.
>
> You will be given a description of the network at Siruseri as well as
>   a source, a target and the number of hops, and your task is to
>   determine the number of routings from the source to the target which
>   have the given number of hops. The answer is to be reported modulo
>   42373.

So as discussed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614429/solving-numroute-in-iarcs) thread , the solution is to calculate the given matrix to the power k where k is the number of routes given.

Here I did the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int> >MatrixMultiplication(std::vector<std::vector<int> >matrix1,std::vector<std::vector<int> >matrix2,int n){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >retMatrix(n,std::vector<int>(n));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                retMatrix[i][j] = retMatrix[i][j] + matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return retMatrix;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int> >MatrixExponentiation(std::vector<std::vector<int> >matrix,int n,int power){
    if(power == 0 || power == 1){
        return matrix;
    }

    if(power%2 == 0){
        return MatrixExponentiation(MatrixMultiplication(matrix,matrix,n),n,power/2);
    }else{
        return MatrixMultiplication(matrix,MatrixExponentiation(MatrixMultiplication(matrix,matrix,n),n,(power-1)/2),n);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >matrix(n,std::vector<int>(n));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    int i ,j ,power;
    std::cin >> i >> j >> power;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >retMax(n,std::vector<int>(n));
    retMax = MatrixExponentiation(matrix,n,power);
    std::cout << matrix[i-1][j-1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the output doesnt matches even for the example case , am I missing something here , or I have to try another approach for this problem?

**Edit** : As @grigor suggested I changed the code for power == 0 to return the identity matrix but the code still produces wrong outputs ,

```
if(power == 0){
        std::vector<std::vector<int> >retMatrix(n,std::vector<int>(n));
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            retMatrix[i][i] = 1;
        }
        return retMatrix;
    }
```

**Note :** I havent wrote the code for modulo thing , do you think it will effect for the example testcase?

Comment: I wonder whether the uninitialized values are indeed 0 as you assume in your code. Can you check that with a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are just printing out the wrong value, change:

```
std::cout << matrix[i-1][j-1] << std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout << retMax [i-1][j-1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: ehh I need more concentration , thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4):

If `power == 0` you should return the identity matrix, not the actual matrix.

Comment: oh you mean the matrix which have 1's in the principal diagonal?

Comment: like it `std::vector<std::vector<int> >retMatrix(n,std::vector<int>(n));
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            retMatrix[i][i] = 1;
        }`

Comment: cause that doesnt even affect the answer

Comment: Depending on the power that case may not be even encountered in the recursion. But that's definitely a bug and needs to be fixed. I can't see any other bugs right now

Comment: @KuntalMajumder, that's right, the identity matrix is the neutral element for production, so this answer validly pointed out a bug.